# Laravel 5.2: DB:raw em relacionamento

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.2

Preciso acessar a tabela `avaliações` e fazer um calculo para calcular a nota de cada produto.

Tentei dessa forma, mas o campo `nota` criado no *DB:raw* não aparece quando tento acessar na *view*, mas consigo acessar os campos da tabela `avaliacoes` normalmente.

```
$produtos = Produto::whereHas('avaliacoes', function($q) {
 $q->select(DB::raw('(CEIL(SUM(qualidade+aparencia+preco) / 3 / COUNT(id))) as nota'));
})->get();
```

Um produto pode ter várias avaliações.

Model avaliacoes

```
class Avaliacoes extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('cliente_id', 'produto_id', 'aparencia', 'preco', 'qualidade');

    public function produto()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Produto');
    }
}
```

Model produto

```
class Produto extends Model
{
    public function avaliacoes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Avaliacoes');
    }
{
```

INNER JOIN

```
$produtos = Produto::join('avaliacoes', 'avaliacoes.produto_id', '=', 'produto.id')
   ->select(DB::raw('(CEIL(SUM(qualidade + aparencia + avaliacoes.preco) / 3 / COUNT(avaliacoes.id))) as nota'), 'produto.*');
```

Comment: se fez errado. se fez um subquery e o que você precisa talvez seja outra coisa ... !!! explique melhor o que precise

Comment: Estou listando todos os produtos cadastrados, juntamente com as notas de cada um que estão armazenadas na tabela avaliacoes.

Comment: Então se pode colocar para mim os dois layout das tabelas? e como elas se relacionam?

Comment: Coloquei as models no post.

Comment: se pode fazer de duas formas, uma é por um método mais um atributo para serializar a outra um inner join, o que acha!

Comment: Tentei com join, mas só lista um produto. O primeiro que tem alguma avaliação. Coloquei o código com join na pergunta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75043/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-diego-vieira).